# frequency of discrete data in excel

Tags: excel, frequency

I'm trying to count how many times a certain number occurs in a column (or row) in excel. I've tried this with the `FREQUENCY` comando in Excel, but this does not give me the right numbers.

So how would I for example be able to count how many times the number 1 occurs in following row:

```
      A B C D E F G H I J 
   1  1 2 1 4 6 1 5 4 2 3 
   2
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use COUNTIF function. First argument of COUNTIF has the range while second is for condition.
So something like that =COUNTIF(A1:A10,1)